# How to refresh first recyclerview data when user clicks on second recyclerview items

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-json

I have first recyclerview in Main Activity and second recycler is in Fragment. I want when user clicks on first recycler item then second recyclerview data should refresh according to the clicked item.

I am still a beginner i dont know how to achieve this?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I think the comment would be more appropriate, but you should describe your problem more clearly.

I still don't understand what this is for, but I can give you a few pointers:

**1. If the recyclerview in Fragment gets data from Activity, you can transfer it by setArguments.**

**2. If the data is not very dependent on Activity, you can write a refresh function in Fragment, then call it from Activity.**

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply..Actually fragment is not getting any data from activity, the data is coming from json, i want if user clicks on activity recycler items then fragment recycler data should change.

Comment: Do you have many Fragments that contain recyclerview that need refresh?
Will each recyclerview item in Activity refresh the data of a recyclerview Fragment?

Comment: no not many only one fragment..yeah each recyclerview item in activity will refresh the fragment's recyclerview.

Comment: If so, please follow method 2.
**In Fragment, there is a refreshData () method.**
**In Activity, when there is an event to click on Recyclerview, call refreshData () in Fragment**